# Can I have the command (dependency) for neo4j in build.sbt for spark 3 and scala 2.12 please?

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, build, sbt

I am unable to add the given "resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"

```
libraryDependencies += "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-connector-apache-spark_${scala.version}" % "4.0.1_for_spark_${spark.version}"
```

dependency command in build.sbt file. This throw me errors Can I know the right command please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is a bit of an issue with Bintray shutting down and our dependancies are returning a Forbidden error.

You can follow the progress about moving to Maven2 [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/issues/334).

In the meantime you can download one of the JARs directly and use it in Scala.

You can find the JARs in the [Github release page](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/releases/tag/4.0.2).

The one you want to use is `neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12-4.0.2_for_spark_3.jar`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you response. I tried to connect atleast through spark shell by using this command first:  $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --jars neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12-4.0.1_for_spark_3.jar

Comment: Then all I did is used the following commands in shell. And the last command throws me an error. Is there anything wrong you can observe with it?

*import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
*val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
*spark.read.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource").option("url", "bolt://localhost:7687").option("authentication.basic.username", "neo4j").option("authentication.basic.password", "1234").option("query", "MATCH (n:Person) WITH n LIMIT 2 RETURN id(n) as id, n.name as name").load().show()

Comment: Unable to connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:143)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalSession.run(InternalSession.java:69)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalSession.run(InternalSession.java:51)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.AbstractQueryRunner.run(AbstractQueryRunner.java:37)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.AbstractQueryRunner.run(AbstractQueryRunner.java:55)

Comment: Well I guess you have some authentication problems. Try to add this option .option("authentication.type", "basic").

Comment: This is no related to the original question though. Open an issue on the connector repository or ask a new question here